# Frontend and backend can't communicate

Tags: angular, koa2, domexception

I'm writing a fullstack app using koa framework in node js for backend and angular 4 for frontend. The problem is that when I make a post request on backend API via frontend (i.e. when I want to sign-in) I get a DOM Exception with text "Network error occurred" and code 19. The backend itself works fine(I've tested it with postman). Here are snippets of my angular code that include the service method with which I make the request and the component method which handles the response.

Service method:

```
authenticate(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post('localhost:3000/api/sign-in',
        JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))

        .map((response: Response) => {
          let token = response.json().token;
          if (token) {
            this.token = token;
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token}));
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
    });
  }
```

Component method:

```
logIn(): void {
    this.authenticationService.authenticate(this.username, this.password)
    .subscribe(result => {
      if (result == true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/people']);
      } else {
        console.log('Username or password incorrect!');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think there is no need to `JSON.stringify` the second parameter of `http.post`. Also, you can open "Network" tab in your browser's Developer Tools and  look at request details to see why it has failed

Comment: Removing `JSON.stringify` doesn't fix the error. Also, I can't see my post requests at all in networks tab. I even added the `HttpHeaders` object as a header for my request with `Content-Type: application/json` and that also didn't fix the error.

Comment: maybe you have enabled some filters in the network tab, take a look in different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you forgot to specify protocol in your URL, it should be something like:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/sign-in', ...
```